# What are the risks/benefits of uploading my website to a public repository?

Tags: python, flask, pypi, python-wheel

I noticed that the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/deploy/) involves use of pip. It looks like it's only used to create a wheel locally that will make setup on a server easier, but as a web dev newbie I'm curious: Does anyone actually go all the way to uploading their websites to a public repository like PyPI? What are the implications (security-related or otherwise) of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should **not** upload private web projects to PyPI (the Python Package Index)! PyPI is for *public, published projects intended to be shared*.

Creating a package for your web project has advantages when deploying to your production servers, but that doesn't require that your package is available on PyPI. The `pip` command-line tool can find and install packages from other repositories, including private Git or Mercurial or SVN repositories or private package indexes too, as well as from the filesystem.

For the record: I've not bothered with creating packages for any of my recent deployed Flask projects I (helped) develop. These were put into production on cloud-hosted hardware and / or in Docker containers, directly from their Github repositories. *Dependencies* are installed with `pip` (as driven by the [Pipenv tool](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in all cases), but the project code itself was just loaded directly from the checkout.

That said, if those projects start using continuous integration down the line, then it may make sense to use the resulting tested code, packaged as wheels, in production too. Publish those wheels to a private index or server; there are several projects and even a few SaaS services already available that let you manage a private package index.

If you do publish to PyPI, then anyone can download your package and analyse how your website works. It'd make it trivial for black-hat hackers to find and exploit security issues in your project that way.

Comment: _private_ GitHub repositories, I assume?

Comment: @NathanielJones: GitHub, Gitlab, Bitbucket, your own servers, any such setup that speaks a supported version control protocol.